# How to prevent double action from simultaneous button touches on UINavigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

In a UINavigation bar, there is a right custom share UIBarButtonItem and a back button in the left UIBarButtonItem.  When simultaneously tapping on both buttons, the app produces a black view, possibly because both buttons are attempting to display a new view simultaneously - the share button presents a UIActivityViewController and the back button a VC from the prior screen.

In looking through similar questions here, I've tried the following solutions but neither prevented a black view from appearing on a simultaneous button touch:

1. Inserting `exclusiveTouch` into ViewDidLoad in the following 2 ways

> a) 
>   `for(UIView *temp in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
>    { [temp setExclusiveTouch:YES]; }`
>
> b) `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setExclusiveTouch:YES];`

2. Applying `self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` after a touch.

Are there other solutions?

Is this related to multi-threading?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @angak I think what we did was to specifically disable the other button after one was touched.

Answer (score 1):

In each touch event handler, add the following line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

When the handler has completed, execute the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

It's up to you to figure out what to consider the end of the handler.  If you're pushing or popping view controllers, you might add that second line to the viewWillAppear of the relevant view controllers.  If you're displaying a modal view controller, you can use the completion handler of `-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]`.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much simple you can use make use of ExclusiveTouch property in this case

> [self.navigationController.navigationBar setExclusiveTouch:YES];

This is a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver handles touch events exclusively.

Setting this property to YES causes the receiver to block the delivery of touch events to other views in the same window. The default value of this property is NO.

Comment: But try to touch the status bar above navigation bar button(s). In this case navigationbar button is pressed. Really strange.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one button to respond to touches at a time, you need to set `exclusiveTouch` for that button, rather than for the parent view.

Put this just after you add your bar button items.

```
for(UIView *temp in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
{
    [temp setExclusiveTouch:YES];
}
```

or you can set `exclusiveTouch` individually for each `UIBarButton` while creating them.

Comment: Thanks PiyushSharma.  This was the first thing I tried - forgot about it - thanks for reminding me. Also, UIBarButtons do not have the exclusiveTouch property.

Comment: I did the same in swift code but not working... can you tell me how to do this... thanks in advance